# How to display a warning at a specific line

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings, intellij-plugin, hint

Quick Intellij plugin Development question.

Can somebody show me a snippet of code on how to display a warning at a specific line?

I want to display a yellow bulb and be able to alt enter.

I don't know if the yellow bulb is part of a warning or just a hint but i would very much appreciate if somebody would show me how to do it.

I tried to find it on idea plugin development but didn't have any luck

> 

```
private List<PsiFile> psiFiles = new ArrayList<PsiFile>();
   public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
   PsiManager psiManager=PsiManager.getInstance(e.getProject());
   Project project = e.getProject();
    VirtualFile srcFile;
        if(e.getProject().getBaseDir().findChild("src") == null)
            return;
        else
        {
            srcFile = e.getProject().getBaseDir().findChild("src");
        }
      //using the buildFilesList i get all the .java files
      buildFilesList(psiManager,srcFile);
     for(PsiFile file : psiFiles)
        //here i would want for a psiFile a warning to be displayed at a specific line
        System.out.println(file);
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code you already have?

Comment: yea sure i have a function which traverses recursively through the Virtual file and i want to parse just the .java files to further process the with antlr.Anyway give a virtualFile i would to display at a specific line a warning like i said in the question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code.

Comment: @TheBlackCat please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855314/idea-intellij-plugin-not-working-in-android-studio-1-5-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to write is an inspection. You don't need to enumerate the files in the project; IntelliJ IDEA will take care of calling your API at the correct moment. You can find a simple example of a plugin that implements an inspection [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/samples/comparingReferences).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855314/idea-intellij-plugin-not-working-in-android-studio-1-5-1