# Idea intellij plugin not working in android studio 1.5.1

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a test plugin for android studio, my plugin works (The actions created are visible ) in Android studio 1.5 when added using "install plugin from disk". But the same jar file is not working in Android studio 1.5.1. 
Below is the plugin.xml file. Please help.

```
<idea-plugin version="2">
<id>com.test.android.studio.plugin</id>
<name>test Android Studio Plugin</name>
<version>1.0</version>
<vendor email="test@test.com" url="http://www.test.com">test test Services Pvt. Ltd.</vendor>

<description>
Android Studio plugin to integrate test SDK
</description>

<change-notes>
 Release 0.0.1: Initial release.
</change-notes>

<!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html for description -->
<idea-version since-build="131"/>

<!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html
     on how to target different products -->
<!-- uncomment to enable plugin in all products-->
<depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>

<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <!-- Add your extensions here -->
</extensions>

<actions>
    <!-- Add your actions here -->
    <group id="Test" class="org.test.plugin.actions.TestMainActionGroup" text="Test" description="Main Test invocation Action"
           popup="true">
        <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"/>

        <action id="testMode" class="org.Test.plugin.actions.TestModeAction" text="Test Mode" description="Test mode action">
            <keyboard-shortcut keymap="$default" first-keystroke="ctrl k"/>
        </action>
        <action id="invocationCode" class="org.Test.plugin.actions.InvocationCodeAction" text="Invocation Code"
                description="Test mode action">
        </action>
        <action id="onlineDoc" class="org.Test.plugin.actions.OnlineDocAction" text="Online Documentation"
                description="Test mode action">
        </action>
        <action id="aboutUs" class="org.Test.plugin.actions.AboutUsAction" text="About Us" description="Test mode action">
        </action>
    </group>

</actions>
```

Comment: Why are you using a custom class for the action group you're adding to the main menu?

Comment: @yole because i want my menu to be displayed to right of help menu. and this is perfectly working as expected in Android studio 1.5.. 
I also added my actions to file menu etc everything works in Android studio 1.5. But my plugin just doesn't work in android studio 1.5.1

Comment: Using a custom class for the group has nothing to do with the place where your menu is displayed.

Comment: @yole oh great. I tried removing that class and it still works as expected.

Comment: @yole , Its awesome .The new group appeared in Android studio 1.5.1 after removing custom group class. But it contains no actions which I have added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer already pointed out the problem is caused by using a custom group class for the action group.

**When you may need custom action group?**

A Custom action group is needed only if you have some custom logic that controls the  behavior of your group of actions, such as the group should be enabled on some selection in the editor,or on mouse hover ,or if you want to add actions dynamically to the group etc.

If the purpose of group is to  group the predefined actions and display it in a particular location the default action group is all that you need 
and it can be easily accomplished by following lines

```
 <group id="Test" text="Test" description="Main Test invocation Action"
       popup="true">
    <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"/>
    <!--List of predefined actions here  -->
</group>
```

Note that the class attribute from the group tag is removed. Now the IDE considers its group as Default Action Group.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by using a custom group class for the action group you add to the main menu. This is not supported in some versions of IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio.

Comment: It is working as you sais. But no actions of the group are visible